# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar una función exportada en http.createServer()?

Tags: nodejs

Resulta que quiero hacer un router sin utilizar Express, con un código creado y mantenido por mi, y al intentar hacer que el **http.createServer()** lo utilice cada vez que el servidor reciba una petición, pero al tratar de utilizarlo como he visto en un vídeo, el servidor (en el navegador) se queda cargando.

He probado con el código que viene para inicializar un servidor en la documentación de NodeJS, y si copio y pego, la página si carga, pero evidentemente el router no, porque no puedo llamarlo a que funcione por defecto.

El código del servidor es:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./app');
http.createServer(app.handleRequest).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

Tengo que decir que el código de arriba está copiado literalmente del vídeo que he visto (aunque este vídeo es del 2016, así que supongo que con los años, esto haya cambiado).

Y en el router es el siguiente:

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

function rennderHTML( path, response ) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function ( error, data ) {
        if ( error ) {
            response.writeHead( 404 );
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write( data );
        }
        response.end();
    });
}

exports = {
    handleRequest: function( request, response ) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' });
        switch ( path ) {
            case '/':
                rennderHTML('./index.html', response);
                break;
            case '/login':
                rennderHTML('./login.html', resposne);
                break;
            default:
                response.writeHead( 404 );
                response.write('Route not defined');
                response.end();
        }
        var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    }
};
```

No hay error de compilación ni de ejecución del servidor, por lo tanto, lo que me falla es la manera en que lo llamo o trato de utilizarlo.

¿Cómo podría hacer que el requestHandler exportado, actúe por defecto como router al hacer una petición a ** http://localhost:3000 ** ( o cualquier dirección/puerto)?

Answer (score 1):

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que me faltaba añadir "module." a exports, por lo tanto no se exportaba como módulo, aunque no me diera error. Por lo tanto la línea:

```
exports = {
```

debería ser:

```
module.exports = {
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda.